# getItemById javascript error

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, custom-form

I'm creating a custom form and am trying to add a button to the form, and have functionality when its clicked.

I don't really have much experience with javascript, so if there is a better approach to this I'm  open to suggestions.

So what I have is

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="test" id="Group1" onclientclick="updateText()" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateText() {
             document.getElementById('<%=Group1.ClientID%>').value="updated";
    }
</script>
```

I've tried both putting this in the form (changing the < and > to < and >) as well as putting it in a content editor webpart (with the asp:Button section remaining on the form, and the script being placed in a .js file). The function calls properly in both instances, but I can't get the getElementById to work-trying an alert with the value also fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<asp:Button UseSubmitBehavior="false"  runat="server" Text="test" 
 id="Group1" onclientclick="updateText(); return false;" />

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function updateText() {             
             document.getElementById('<%=Group1.ClientID%>').value="updated";
             return false; 
    } 
</script>
```

Returning false will remove the postback.

<asp:controlname /> type directives won't work in a content editor. In asp or a content editor you can do this with a regular html button instead of an asp control if you want to.

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="test" onclick="updateText2();"/>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function updateText2() {            
             document.getElementById('btn').value="updated";             
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that was a question I had. I am receiving the error:

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Wed, 29 Aug 2012 20:33:38 UTC


Message: Object expected
Line: 881
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: <form url>

Comment: Is there more to the error? Object expected on line 881 is too vague. What code is on that line?

Comment: Your second solution worked, thanks! The failing line was the getItemById call